# Google maps API - view my charges?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using the google maps and geocoding apis. As they state there is a cost depending on how many searches that you do with your API key. So, is there any way I can see what my current costs are - so I don't break the bank.

Thanks,

Ward

Comment: you can see you traffic usage in your google  console developer

Comment: scaisedge thanks great answer,